# Angular creating service with get request using HttpClient, question with types of get request

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient, angular-httpclient

I was trying to practice on Angular, I am having trouble with get requests types
[Angular Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gtkhnt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fposts.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fpost.ts)

```
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { catchError, map, Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';



@Injectable({
  providedIn:'root'
})
export class PostsService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  getPosts():Observable<Post[]>{
    return this.http.get<any>('https://dummyjson.com/posts').pipe(
    map(res=> res.posts),
      catchError(err=>{
        console.log(err)
        return throwError(()=>err)
      })
    )
  }
}
interface PostResponse{
  limit: number
  posts: string[]
  skip: number
  total: number
}
interface Post {
  body: string
id: number
reactions: number
tags: string[]
title: string
userId: number
}
```

Generally I bypass this with `any` type instead of `PostResponse` or `Post[]` but I think it is not the best practice, `map` operator makes things more complicated I suppose.
So what should `get` requests type be in this kind of situation?

Comment: I'm confused, why aren't you using the data structures defined above?

Comment: When I used them, they gave me type error, I tried both, API response return an object but I need just ' posts' , check Stackblitz, you can see errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are declaring the `posts` property of the `PostResponse` as type `string[]`, but it should be type `Post[]`:

```js
interface PostResponse {
  limit : number;
  skip  : number;
  total : number;
  posts : Post[];
}
```